# How to break a word with two 50% table cells?

Tags: html, css, cell, css-tables

I'm trying to break long words in a table of two 50% width cells.
I have already tried `word-wrap: break-word;` but it's not helping.

**HTML**

```
<section class="table-wrapper">
    <section class="table-left">
        <p>LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG</p>
    </section>
    <section class="table-right">
        <p>SHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOORT</p>
    </section>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-wrapper {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-left, .table-right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lu50tLmf/

It is breaking the whole element size and it is too large if the word is too long. How can I fix this?

Comment: Take off `display:table-cell;` and `word-wrap:break-word;` will work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu50tLmf/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `word-break` property.

> Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line

In `.table-left, .table-right`:

Remove `display:table-cell;`

Add `word-break:break-all;`

Change to this:

```
.table-wrapper {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-left, .table-right {
    width: 50%;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d23614cL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add "`word-break:break-all;`" property to "

```
.table-left, .table-right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

"

**Here is the working Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lu50tLmf/4/**

Answer (score 0):

Use the below modified CSS

```
.table-wrapper {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:5px 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

.table-left, .table-right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```